# Some Push Notifications sent from Azure Notification Hub not received on iOS devices

Tags: azure, notifications, xamarin.ios

So I'm working with the Azure Notification hub for my Xamarin.iOS project. I've followed the tutorial from Azure in setting up my hub and configuring the necessary certificates. I'm working with a development environment and have sent a couple of test notifications from the Notification hub which have been received successfully.

The challenge I have is consistency. The devices stop receiving notifications after a while. There are no APNS errors on the hub and it shows that all the notifications have been sent successfully. I'm not sure at what point these fail.

Has anyone else experienced this? During registration, I am using the device token as is, without changing it. I'm also passing in a tag for each user during registration. The tag is simply the device token which has been stripped of the '< >' characters.

Because I see no errors on the notification hub, I'm unable to pinpoint the real issue as to why some notifications fail to reach the devices.

I'm also generating an adhoc ipa with the release build, which I install via iTunes and an App Store ipa still in testing which I install via TestFlight. Should I still be using the sandbox environment and a development SSL certificate? These ipa(s) are still for testing purposes. We're not in production yet.

I would truly appreciate any assistance.

Below is my code:

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        try
        {

            Hub = new SBNotificationHub(ConnectionString, NotificationHubPath);

            Hub.UnregisterAllAsync(deviceToken, (error) =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error calling Unregister: {0}", error);
                    return;
                }
            });

            var newToken = FormatTheString(deviceToken.ToString());
            var finalTag = newToken.Replace(" ",String.Empty);
            var tags = new NSSet(finalTag); // create tags if you want
            Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) =>
            {
                if (errorCallback != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " + errorCallback);
            });


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE**

I've been able to identify the problem. After more testing, I've realized that the registrations are deleted from my notification hub after a few test messages. So when testing in debug mode, the messages are always delivered. However, when I generate release builds and test on those, they are delivered for a while and then they fail completely.

This causes `Bad Channel Errors` and `Invalid Channel Errors`. So what happens in this case is the debug ipa registration is registered on the hub. When I delete this ipa and install a release build(Ad hoc or App Store version), a new registration is saved on the hub. So when I send out new test notifications, it sends to 'both' devices, when in actual sense, it's only one device. After a few tests, the APNs realizes there's an invalid registration id, it closes the connection hence the `Bad Channel Errors`.

Is there a way I can delete or overwrite the previous registrations from the hub?

Comment: with adhoc builds the device can send both dev and prod tokens depending on the certificates created. I would suggest redoing your certificates. We found this out the hard way.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt I've updated my question with an explanation on what the issue is. Do you have any idea how I can overwrite or delete any previous registration Ids from the hub?